# Two bodies A and B fell from rest Compare the time of arrival of objects A and B to Earth

Tags: gravity, time

Two bodies A and B fell from rest from a height of 100 m, and body A reached the ground
Directly while body B hits an inclined surface making its velocity horizontal as shown in the figure,
Compare the time of arrival of objects A and B to Earth.

[image]

I know there is a lack of required data but this is the question I get . I tried the following :

> body A

it was clear there i have

$V_{0}=0$   ,  $H = 100 $   , $g = 9.81$

there for

$ H=V_{0}t+\frac{1}{2}gt^{2} $
$t = 4.52 sec $

> body B

when I come to body i do the from B point to D point
$t_{1}=3.192sec$

then I get the velocity from equation
$v=V_{0}+gt$
$v=31.32 m/sec$

**then I do think of it as a projectile problem**
$\theta = 0$  ,  $u=31.32$  , $H=50$ ,  $g=9.81$
$H = u \cos \theta t + \frac{1}{2}gt^{2}$
$t_{2}=1.32$ or $t=-7.07 $

from that I get:
$t_{total}=t_{1}+t_{2}=3.19+1.32=4.51 sec$
**which is the same as point A and now I confusing my self ...**

Comment: You have shown no effort

Comment: @BobD I try to solve it for 3 month but I didn't get satisfied with my answer + this is my first time asking here can you help what i have to show more ?

Comment: Check out this guide to asking homework like questions. https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange

Comment: @mody That's OK. Just show us what you tried.

Comment: how about now is there any thing that I am missing ?

Answer (score 2):

Body A will fall earlier in this case .
Upto point D both bodies have same velocity and reach point D simultaneously since they are dropped from the same height .But after striking the incline the velocity of B becomes horizontal i.e its vertical velocity is zero. Now ,how fast a body falls depends only on the vertical velocity and not on the horizontal velocity.So after collision B has zero vertical velocity but A has some non zero vertical velocity and both undergo same acceleration .So A falls faster.

Let time taken by A = $t_a$.

$$ s=ut+\frac12at^2$$
But u=0;

so,
$$s=\frac12at^2$$or, $$ t=\sqrt\frac{2s}{g}$$
Putting s=100 m and g=9.8 m$s^{-2}$ $t_a$=4.52 s

For B ,time taken to travel BD = $\sqrt\frac{2\times 50}{9.8}$ = 3.19 s

time taken to travel DF =$\sqrt\frac{2\times 50}{9.8}$ = 3.19 s

Total time of travel for B ($t_b$)= 3.19 s + 3.19 s = 6.39 s

Now , $\frac {t_a }{t_b}$ = 0.707

Clearly B takes more time than A.

**NOTE : THE EFFECT OF TERMINAL VELOCITY HAS BEEN NEGLECTED DUE TO LACK OF REQUIRED DATA**

Comment: Let me know if any part is unclear

Comment: What is apparently unclear is the point of this forum.  The point is to help people understand aspects of physics that may be unclear.   It is explicitly *not* the point to present solutions to homework problems (although I admit that policy is not clearly stated.)  Please rewrite your answer in a way that provides guidance without actually solving the problem.  (If you don't want to do that, you can delete your answer.)

Comment: @shaihorowitz  You are right, of course.   But your link is to a question about *asking* questions.   That article has been cited as a statement of the policy *but it's hard to find*.  I've been asking for a clear up-front statement of the policy [*for years*](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7636/5739).

Comment: According to me my answer has a detailed analysis of the phenomenon and the mathematical solution . If I am to provide only the hint for the problem I need to know how much the person asking the question knows about physics , where they have a working knowledge of vectors etc.Since I did not have that information I decided to present the solution as well as the explanation.

Comment: @garyp sorry i meant to link to the thing that question linked to. Namely the policy is well written out at the math stack exchange and most of the points made transfer to this site as well. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/415/homework-questions-avoiding-giving-a-complete-solution

Comment: @shaihorowitz  True again.  But would a new arrival here look on the Math site for instructions?

Comment: @Möbius I think that at the incline the body didn't stop because if you say that it is like you neglecting the acceleration of gravity wouldn't you ?

Comment: they will fall at the same moment I guess

Comment: I don't care if my solution is incorrect but I see many time that in physics experiment that if we shot a ball horizontally with another one dropping down vertically they will hit the ground at the same time

Comment: You are correct but when "if we shot a ball horizontally with another one dropping down vertically " that happens both bodies have initial vertical velocity 0 but here at D vertical velocity of A is not zero but that of B is zero so A falls faster

Comment: In you answer you make the mistake when you take u=31.32 m/s because at D the velocity is purely horizontal which suggests that the vertical velocity is zero so u at D must be zero.Always keep in mind that vertical displacement happens only due to vertical velocity. Horizontal velocity has no contribution to vertical displacement at all and at D this vertical velocity is zero after collision since the question says that the velocity is purely horizontal at D.

Comment: Also when a body stops it doesn't mean that the force on it or its acceleration  is zero.It only means its velocity is zero.For example when you throw a ball vertically upwards the ball has zero velocity at the topmost point of its path so at this point it momentarily comes to rest even though acceleration due to gravity is still present. So when I say vertical velocity at D is zero it doesn't mean that I am neglecting acceleration due to gravity .

Comment: Let me know what you think.

Comment: @Möbius Wow I am got it now , Thank you very very much for your help I appreciate that it was clearly explained I have test after 4 days now I am able to understand this vertical and horizontal motion very well I which you the best .. thanks again

Comment: Happy to help!!